# Choose First Option in DropDown list

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu, oracle10g, oledb

How my application works is the user will select a row from a gridview with various values. When they select it, it will re-direct to another page that displays all the information to update it.

Issue I face is:

I have a drop down list the doesn't show all the listing options from the database + display the value populated by the previous sql statement as the first option. How do I do this?

an example:

The gridview that is chosen, the category = 'Health'. Once selected, it re-directs to the new page to update; however, category = 'Computers' is the first option displayed instead of 'Health'

So How do I make the top option equal Health and display the rest below?

[image]

I have tried `order by category` but of course that makes 'Computer' the first option.

I then tried  `where category =value` but that only shows 'Health' as an option instead of all the category options.

Any suggestions?

```
'index from previous sql statement (Index/Item 2 is category)
Dim categoryV = DsAds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2)

Dim ClassStrCat As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM t_cat order by category = '" & categoryV & "'", conn)
   OracleDataAdapterAds.SelectCommand = ClassStrCat
   CategoryList.DataSource = DsAds
   CategoryList.DataMember = "t_class"
   CategoryList.DataBind()

   Dim ClassStrCat2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM t_cat order by category ", conn)
   Dim OracleDataAdapterAds2 As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter
   OracleDataAdapterAds2.SelectCommand = ClassStrCat2

   Dim DsAds2 As DataSet = New DataSet
   DsAds2.Clear()

   OracleDataAdapterAds2.Fill(DsAds2, "t_class")
   CategoryList.DataSource = DsAds2
   CategoryList.DataMember = "t_class"
   CategoryList.DataBind()
```

Comment: This code is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked. Look into parameterized queries.

Comment: My code is restricted based on where it displays. The website is restricted which is where the application links from.

Comment: That's irrelevant. Lots of hacks are inside jobs, or the result of compromised machines inside your network. Using string concatentation to put data into a query is amateurish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works so I use the following (plus the code I already have to keep the "order by category") at the end of my coding:

```
CategoryList.Items.FindByText(categoryV).Selected = True
```

Answer (score 1):

After filling the combo box, simply set it's `SelectedIndex` to the index of the string you're looking for by using `FindString` or `FindStringExact`. They both return an integer, which is the index of the desired string.

```
CategoryList.SelectedIndex = CategoryList.FindStringExact("Health")
```

If `FindString` or `FindExactString` can't find what you specified, it will return -1

Comment: When I use FindStringExact it flags an error saying it isn't a member of System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList

Also... since what will be displayed inside the `FindStringExact("")` is based on the sql statement from previous page, can I do something like...

`CategoryList.SelectedIndex = categoryV` since the category chosen is dynamic? I'm worried I can't because there is a int/string conversion issue

Comment: I figured it out with your help of SelectedIndex

Comment: Oh, Web, not WinForms. I don't work with Web developing, but can you set the CategoryList.SelectedValue = "Health", or if you *know* that index 2 will always be "Health", you can set the SelectedIndex = 2, but that's not a good design. Alternatively, you could use a For Loop to go through the CategoryList.Items, and if an item equals "Health", then save that index and set it as the SelectedIndex.

Comment: Health isn't always 2 but index 2 is where the chosen category will always be. However, the option I chose in my answer below worked. I will look into your suggestion though. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

"So How do I make the top option equal Health and display the rest below?"
You can't if is order by .. 
1) you can remove the 2 records above
or
2) SelectedIndex(2) to set focus on Health.

3) I faced with a similar situation in a medical app, and I added on top my previous selected Category (Health), and deleted from his normal position.

I remeber Paint was the right moment to do ..

```
 Private Sub dgv1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles dgv1.Paint
     '.. IF categotyV
 End Sub
```

Comment: If I do CategoryList.SelectedIndex(categoryV) it says property access must assign to property or use it's value. So how do I pull categoryV's string value?

Comment: did you tyied Keith solution ? : CategoryList.SelectedIndex = CategoryList.FindStringExact("Health")

Comment: Depend on what you want to achieve .. even narue's answer is cool

Comment: Keiths isn't what I want because it won't always be Health.